# Which file contains the table creation script in wordpress in multinetwork environment

Tags: wordpress

I have searched for a while and still cannot find the correponding file which contains the table creation script in wordpress multinetwork environment.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no table creation script, it just uses the database prefix + blog id + table name when creating tables for a particular site, for example if the prefix is `wp_` for a regular WordPress install, it becomes `wp_2_` for blog id 2, and so on...

The code that does this in the source is here http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L670